# c#: have my interface react to a timer elapsed function

Tags: c#

in my class i have this simple timer:

```
public ElapsedEventHandler timerElapsed;
_validityTimer.Elapsed += timerElapsed;
```

I created an interface to inject into another serivce:

```
public interface ILocalPermissionManager
{
    public ElapsedEventHandler timerElapsed;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is by using this interface inside another service I can react to the timed event from my base class. However, it wont let me do this as:

"interfaces cannot have instance level data members".

How could I create a reaction in my class that gets my interface injected that respons to a timer elapsed?

Thank you

Comment: Interface are mostly used to extract common functionality, in your case you have a field so you could use an abstract class in this case I would make access protected. 
Another option would be that the interface has a method which returns the handler.

Comment: How does your/a minimal implementation of ILocalPermissionManager looks and how does the code look that connects an instance of that implementation to the Timers event?

Comment: timerElapsed should be a property though and then implemented in a "real" class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expose an `event` in an interface. Here is an example based on your code:

```
public interface ILocalPermissionManager
{
    event ElapsedEventHandler TimerElapsed;
}
```

With this in place, you allow consumers to attach handlers to the event like normal.

Then, in the implementation, you can do something like this to redirect the handlers to the actual underlying event on the timer:

```
public sealed class LocalPermissionManager : ILocalPermissionManager
{
    private readonly Timer _timer;

    public LocalPermissionManager()
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
    }

    public event ElapsedEventHandler TimerElapsed
    {
        add => _timer.Elapsed += value;
        remove => _timer.Elapsed -= value;
    }
}
```

Notice how we are implementing the `add` and `remove` components of the event, and passing the addition/removal to another event property inside of the class.

Comment: Yes, an event is to a delegate field what a property is to another field. The `public` modifier is not required in the interface declaration.

Comment: Good catch on the access modifier @OlivierJacot-Descombes, removing it ;)

Comment: Thank you! This was working very fine for me. With the event I was able to attach event handlers outside the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Please check and try something like,

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public interface ILocalPermissionManager
{
    event ElapsedEventHandler TimerElapsed;
}

public class YourClass : ILocalPermissionManager
{
    private readonly Timer _validityTimer;

    public event ElapsedEventHandler TimerElapsed;

    public YourClass()
    {
        _validityTimer = new Timer();
        _validityTimer.Elapsed += TimerElapsedHandler;
        // Set up your timer properties (e.g., _validityTimer.Interval, etc.)
        _validityTimer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerElapsedHandler(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Timer elapsed logic
        OnTimerElapsed(e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnTimerElapsed(ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Raise the TimerElapsed event
        TimerElapsed?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}

public class AnotherClass : ILocalPermissionManager
{
    public AnotherClass(ILocalPermissionManager localPermissionManager)
    {
        localPermissionManager.TimerElapsed += HandleTimerElapsed;
    }

    private void HandleTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // React to the timer elapsed event
        Console.WriteLine("Timer elapsed in AnotherClass");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
        AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass(yourClass);

        // Keep the program running
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```